# Unable to compile glade 3.8.5 in ubuntu yakkety

Tags: command-line, compiling, gtk, make, glade

I have been trying to install glade version 3.8.5, which I need to work on an application based on gtk2 and the libglade library. I am running on Ubuntu 16.10, yakkety.

Since the glade-gtk2 package corresponding to glade 3.8.5 has not been published for yakkety, I downloaded the source archive on the GNOME website (http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/glade3/3.8/).
When running the `make` command, it ends with the following errors:

```
glade-editor-property.c: In function 'glade_eprop_object_dialog_title':  
glade-editor-property.c:2722:7: error: format not a string literal, argument types not checked [-Werror=format-nonliteral]  
(GLADE_PARAM_SPEC_OBJECTS (eprop->klass->pspec))));  
   ^  
glade-editor-property.c:2726:3: error: format not a string literal, argument types not checked [-Werror=format-nonliteral]  
   return g_strdup_printf (format, adaptor->title);  
   ^~~~~~  
glade-editor-property.c:2732:5: error: format not a string literal, argument types not checked [-Werror=format-nonliteral]  
 (eprop->klass->pspec->value_type));  
 ^  
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors  
Makefile:852: recipe for target 'libgladeui_1_la-glade-editor-property.lo' failed  
make[3]: [libgladeui_1_la-glade-editor-property.lo] Error 1  
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/theo/Downloads/glade3-3.8.5/gladeui'  
Makefile:575: recipe for target 'all' failed  
make[2]: [all] Error 2  
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/theo/Downloads/glade3-3.8.5/gladeui'  
Makefile:492: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed  
make[1]:  [all-recursive] Error 1  
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/theo/Downloads/glade3-3.8.5'  
Makefile:421: recipe for target 'all' failed  
make:  [all] Error 2
```

What could be the problem here, and how can I fix it to get the installation done? My coworker has the same issue.

Please note that using the glade 3.8.0 package from Ubuntu trusty (14.04) is not an option, because a known bug makes me unable to open most of my glade files (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glade/+bug/1242865)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem has been resolved since the release of Ubuntu 17.10, as I am now able to install glade version 3.8.**6** after downloading it from the mentioned source (http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/glade3/3.8/).

I still ran in a bug that would make glade crash whenever it tries to load a dialog window, but I was able to fix it thanks to the following tutorial: https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1641